Как на python в библиотеке telebot при нажатии Inline кнопки вывести вот так текст?
Пример:
https://ibb.co/LzrYz8t
ㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤ

Для начала, приводите пример кода, который сами пытались сделать. Если не знаете код уведомления, то хотя бы код для кнопки могли добавить.
И скриншот можно не ссылкой оставлять.
А вообще, всё легко находится в документации за пару минут, вместо ожидания ответов.
А теперь к ответу:
bot.answer_callback_query — позволяет высветить пользователю уведомление, после нажатия на кнопку;
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def test(message): # здесь всё, как обычно;
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    btn = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Нажми на меня", callback_data="alert")
    markup.add(btn)

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text='Сообщение', reply_markup=markup)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda callback: True)
def callback_handler(callback):
    if callback.data == 'alert':
        # в ответ даём уведомление;
        bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query_id=callback.id, show_alert=False, text='Вы нажали на кнопку!')

Параметр show_alert позволяет изменить тип уведомления. Если False, то уведомление появится и само исчезнет, но при True его нужно будет самостоятельно закрыть, что может быть удобно при очень важных уведомлениях.
В мобильной и десктопной версии отличаются внешне.

bot.answer_callback_query и параметр show_alert=True.

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]
